# How to allow update but not insert a new branch on firebase rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

The title isn't good but couldn't find a way to shorter it.

lets say i've a firebase database like this

```
shop{
  $category:{
    product1:{},
    product2:{},
    //so on
  }
}
```

how can i write i rule to allow users to create new products ONLY IF the `category` already exists?

Comment: I think you should consider handling this in your application business logic, not in Firebase Rules.

Comment: anyone can mock requests to firebase database... this is a very useless task, but a hacker with enough knowledge wouldn't take long...

Comment: Refer this, https://github.com/Pradyuman7/CommonFirebaseJSON, it might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
{
    "shop": {
        "$category": {
            ".write": "root.child('shop').child($category).exists()"
        }
    }
}
```

This should allow write in shop/$category/anything if shop/$category exists.